# If statement not executing properly in ByVal Target As Range

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

This code checks cell ranges based on the criteria provided in the Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range). It works for the most part except for this one anomaly. When range SalesPrice changes it checks the loanamount value, "If my loan amount is under 271,050 and checkbox1.value is true" it goes to the next routine (this is correct behavior).  But if I change the SalesPrice which re-calculates LoanAmount to a number that causes the LoanAmount to go over 271050 the MsgBox code does not execute. But if I retype the same SalesPrice again it does execute. So in order for it to work properly I have to type in the SalesPrice twice if chkbox1.value was initially checked for the code to detect that the LoanAmount is too high.

```
If Target.Address = "$D$5" Then 'Sales Price
If Range("LoanProgram").Value Like "*HFA Bond Miami*" And _
Range("SalesPrice").Value > 317646 Then MsgBox "Miami-Dade Bond Max Sales 
Price is $317,646"
If Range("LoanAmount").Value > 271050 And Sheets("Main").CheckBox1.Value = 
True Then
MsgBox "MDEAT Max Loan Amount is $271,050"
Sheets("Main").CheckBox1.Value = False
End If
```

Comment: The worksheet_change event would only kick in if you manually change D5, if you manually change anywhere on the sheet, the code will check if it was D5, if it was not, then it will exit the sub. Calculations are not worksheet_change events.

Comment: Can you indent your code correctly and make sure the line breaks are correct please? It is not clear if your `If` statements are single line statements or not. The code as it is would not compile. Best is to copy/past the code here and use Ctrl + K to format it as code block.

Comment: D5 is manually being entered.

Answer (score 0):

Import:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Address = "$D$5"
    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

save the file close it and reopen it in order to reset Application.EnableEvents.

Comment: Didn't work, I placed "Application.EnableEvents = False" it right after the "If Target.Address = "$D$5" Then" line and place "Application.EnableEvents = True" after the "End If"

Comment: You can enableEvents with `Application.EnableEvents = True` Assigned to a button, or you can enter it in the "immediate window" in the vba editor, great help when testing code.

Comment: You have a quote after If"

Comment: just a note but your `If` has no `Then` ;)